# C can't open file using a variable

Tags: c, linux

I need to open a file located on Desktop(Linux). If i write the location as a string inside the fopen() function it works, but if i pass it as a variable, it doesn't work. Here is my code :

```
fp = fopen(readPathToFile, "r");
if (!fp){
       printf("Failed to open text file\n");
       exit(1);
}
else{
      fscanf(fp,"%s",line);
      printf("File read: %s",line);
}
```

If i write it like this, it shows me the content of file :

```
fp = fopen("home/user/Desktop/test.txt", "r");
    if (!fp){
           printf("Failed to open text file\n");
           exit(1);
    }
    else{
          fscanf(fp,"%s",line);
          printf("File read: %s",line);
    }
```

The child process opens the file. Here is my full code

```
   #include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define READ  0
#define WRITE 1
int main ()
{
  pid_t pid;

  int mypipefd[2];
 id_t child_pid;
 char line[100];
 char *pathToFile[100];
 FILE *fp;
 char buff[255];
 /* create the pipe */
  if (pipe(mypipefd) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Pipe failed");
    return 1;
  }

 child_pid = fork () ;

    if (child_pid > 0) {
        printf("Introduceti locatia catre fisier:");
        fgets(pathToFile, 100, stdin);
        close(mypipefd[READ]);
        write(mypipefd[WRITE], &pathToFile, sizeof(pathToFile));
        close(mypipefd[WRITE]);
        printf("parent: write value : %s",pathToFile);
    }
    else if (child_pid < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fork failed");
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        char *readPathToFile[100];
        close(mypipefd[WRITE]);
        read(mypipefd[READ], &readPathToFile, sizeof(readPathToFile));
        close(mypipefd[READ]);
        printf("child: read value : %s",readPathToFile);
        fp = fopen(readPathToFile, "r");
        if (!fp)
        {
            printf("Failed to open text file\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        else{
            fscanf(fp,"%s",line);
            printf("File read: %s",line);
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show us how you declare and assign `readPathToFile`.

Comment: You must be passing something wrong in readPathToFile.

Comment: Wild assed guess: `readPathToFile` contains a newline at the end.

Comment: Or readPathToFile is a char, not a char pointer....

Comment: @Jens not that wild:)   I would have bet my buttered toast and black coffee  on it.

Comment: Well, a modest amount of debugging should .... owait... C tag :(

Comment: (Making more toast now, and popcorn...This is going to be a great ending!)

Comment: You have check that readPathToFile is a char pointer or a fixed length char type.

Comment: I know I'm probably wasting my time, but.. run it under your debugger, break on the fopen and inspect the value of readPathToFile* IN HEX, BYTE_BY_BYTE.

Comment: WHOA!  Didn't see that one coming!

Comment: `char *pathToFile[100]` is a `char**`. You want `char pathToFile[100]` (no *)

Comment: It gives me the same result

Comment: Debugger....................

Comment: @user3121023 you mean...my buttered toast is safe?

Comment: If i try to debug it it gives me this message first on console : "warning: GDB: Failed to se controlling terminal: Operation not permitted". Also it shows me nothing on debugger

Comment: Ty user3121023 ! worked

Comment: @Ben Try the suggestions [given here](http://askubuntu.com/q/271887) (for the GDB issue)

Comment: "home/user/Desktop/test.txt" should probably be "/home/user/Desktop/test.txt". Your problem may be due to absolute vs relative path.

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler did not warn you about the type mismatch in

```
char *pathToFile[100];
fgets(pathToFile, 100, stdin);
```

(array of 100 pointers-to-char versus array of 100 chars)? Did you turn warnings off?

Also note that `fgets` retains the newline. Your file name probably does not end with a newline. You should replace it with a NUL (zero) byte.

Typically you don't need a debugger to track these down. A little bit of `printf` debugging can do wonders. :-)

Comment: if OP does not fix its debugger environment, it will post again next week:(

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so this is the root of your problem:

```
char *pathToFile[100];
```

This declares `pathToFile` as a 100-element array of *pointers* to `char`, not a 100-element array of `char`.  The first thing you need to do is change that declaration to

```
char pathToFile[100];
```

Secondly, `fgets` will save the trailing newline from your input to the target buffer if there's room, so you'll need to remove that newline from the input:

```
char *newline = strchr( pathToFile, '\n' );
if ( newline )
  *newline = 0;
```